# Wordpress posts_where?

Tags: wordpress, filter, permissions

I'm trying to setup a wordpress site that uses the private/public posts to hide private post for non logged in users and allow authors to see all users private posts.

I'm trying to set this up using "posts_where" filter but can't get it to work.

this is my loop/query code, note I need to use two loops on the page that both filter private posts. I have also allowed authors to be able to see private posts in functions.php

```
<?php
// filter private posts in user not permitted to view
function privates_control($where) {
    if( current_user_can('read_private_posts')) return $where;
    global $wpdb;
    return " $where AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status != 'private' "; // or add your     
custom status
}
$feature_args =  array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'work', 'people', 'events' ),    
'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DSC');
$feature_query = new WP_Query();
add_filter('posts_where', 'privates_control');
$feature_query->query($feature_args);
?>

<?php if ($feature_query->have_posts()) : while ($feature_query->have_posts()) :  
$feature_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>

<?php
 // this is the first loop
$box_args =  array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'work', 'people', 'events' ),    
'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DSC');
$boxes_query = new WP_Query();
add_filter('posts_where', 'privates_control');
$boxes_query->query($box_args);
?>
// this is the first loop
<?php if ($boxes_query->have_posts()) : while ($boxes_query->have_posts()) :  
$boxes_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

hope someone understands this mess, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this to your `$args` (or `$feature_args`  ) after setting them :

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  // this will add argument of showing also private to all logged in users
  // or any other condition ou want 
  $args['post_status'][] = 'private';
}
```

Comment: Ok so don't use the post_where hook? just a simple WP_Query with that conditional?

Comment: There is no ONE way to achieve things. use whatever is more comfortable to you.